# Check steps for building a common multi-model form using Yii

Tags: yii

Here's the scenario (a very common one):

- A team registration form.
- A team can have several members, so the user can add several members.
- At least one member should be inserted.

The user should be allowed to:

- A) Fill in team details (name, logo, etc…);
- B) Being notified inline if some of the fields are not correct.
- C) Choose to Either Insert the team or make it publicly available by Publish it and see the related validation rules for each choice.
- D) Add more members (trough a ADD MEMBER button) that will display more form fields to be filled in related to another model. (the user may also remove those fields);

I'm thinking about following the following steps, before doing so, however, I would like to request a look for those much more experienced then me on such subjects.

Can you please validate the above steps and point possible important missing points ?

We need to:

**For A)**

- Render the form using  `CActiveForm`;

**For B)**

- We need to set `enableClientValidation` to `true`;
- We need to `render both models` on one single form;

**For C)**

- Create validation model `scenarios`.
- Create a checkbox that will change the scenario to either Insert or Publish when checked

  - `Ajax form validation` should be `enable` as well ;

**For D)**

- on click, we need to show/hide additional fieldsets.
- we need to collect `tabular input` for members.
- we need to use renderPartial

Am I missing something important that I should look at before starting to code this using Yii ? Would you use different steps? If so, can you please share ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to display the full potential of the Yii framework, you would rather extend CFormModel to include the various models you want to integrate in a single form.

Why? Because the CActiveForm class you want to use is thought to work with a single model. Otherwise you will have to include several forms, one for each model, find a way to submit all of them at once (through Javascript) when the user commits the creation action, and connect them on the server side.

Another simple approach would be to split the process so that you let the user first create the Team using the Team model with CActiveForm and then, once the team has been created, redirect the user, for example to `team/view/1`, and render a tabular form for the members data, again using a single model with CActiveForm. And if you want to assure that at least one member exists for every team, you would hold it in the Team model, for example Team.leader_member.

I hope it helps. Cheers.